# Static compression in IIS does not work for htm, js files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compression, iis-7.5

I'm trying to configure IIS 7.5 to compress static htm and js files. Does anyone know why it does not work for me? Here is my web.config for the web site:

```
    <httpCompression>          
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
```

Compression starts working when I set doDynamicCompression to true. But I can't use this option because it is disabled at my hosting.

Thank you.

Comment: I find the same issue. It seems like CSS files with compress if staticcompression is on. But I need dynamicCompression on for js. And if I do that it does .aspx as well. Further the httpCompression scheme seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enabling Http caching and compression in IIS 7 for asp.net websites - Anil Kasalanati](http://weblogs.asp.net/anilkasalanati/archive/2010/12/29/enabling-http-caching-and-compression-in-iis-7-for-asp-net-websites.aspx)

How about this? Checkyour  applicationHost.config file.

Comment: Good link, thanks. I found the mismatch for mime types in applicationHost.config, fixed it but it did not help me.

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think the compression is not working?  Check the Event View logs.  Static Compression module will sometimes throw an error saying the directory being used is invalid (mostly because it needs write permissions).

Double check with Fiddler or another HTTP debugging tool to be sure that the client is sending "Accept-Encoding" of GZIP/Deflate.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes, that's how I detect if compression is working - looking at response http headers. It sends Content-Encoding: gzip only when doDynamicCompression="true". Nothing in the event logs, I even tried to give all permissions to Everyone for the "C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" folder - did not help.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the mimeType="application/x-javascript" from the dynamicTypes but left it in staticTypes.  That allowed me to turn off dynamicCompression but still have javascript compressed.

I've read some posts that suggest that when you have the same mimeType in both dynamic and static, the value in dynamic wins.  When dynamicCompression is off, but there is a match for it in the dynamicTypes, javascript is treated as dynamic and therefore off.

That doesn't explain why CSS works because mimeType="text/*" is in both places. IIS must do a better job of determining dynamic vs. static content when it comes to CSS, or any text/*.