# IIS 7.5 no static or dynamic compression

Tags: asp-classic, compression, gzip, iis-7.5

I can't get static or dynamic compression to work on a new server for .ASP, .JS or .CSS files.

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit.  Under IIS Role Services, I have ASP installed, as well as static and dynamic compression.  I'm using DefaultAppPool with the standard ApplicationPoolIdentity.  I've enabled all the compression options for the site.

Here's the relevant section of my applicationHost.config (this is all under system.webServer):

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>

<serverRuntime frequentHitThreshold="1" />

<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
```

So I turned on failed request tracing to get a better view.

For ASP, it appears to skip static and dynamic compression entirely.  There is no entry for DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_SUCCESS or DYNAMIC COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS.

For CSS and JS, it attempts static compression but fails:

```
STATIC_COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS     Reason="NO_MATCHING_SCHEME"
```

I can't find any solid documentation online about what NO_MATCHING_SCHEME means.  Help!

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com

Comment: I wondered about that. I looked through nearly every post I could find about compression, and saw a bunch of questions (and answers) here on stackoverflow.com. I'll try posting it over there too. Thanks.

Comment: Is DefaultAppPool configured to Classic or Integrated mode?

Comment: Linked questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515426/static-compression-in-iis-does-not-work-for-htm-js-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662764/dynamic-compression-not-working-iis-7-5

Comment: Anybody have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have application pool configured to use Classic mode:

[Some settings in the system.webServer section apply only to IIS 7.0 Integrated mode and do not apply to Classic mode.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763179.aspx)

Try to set up compression via [IIS Manager](http://blogs.iis.net/sbradk/archive/2011/04/28/iis-compression.aspx) UI.

Comment: DefaultAppPool is configured to Integrated. I've tried switching it to classic and it makes no difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662764/dynamic-compression-not-working-iis-7-5 is actually very similar to my problem... I get the same status messages for dynamic compression on the ASP files when I do failed request tracing.

Comment: Also, I've set up compression via IIS Manager UI, and finally resorted to trying to tweak applicationHost.config. No luck either way. I'm wondering if config file is screwed up. Can anyone send me a applicationHost.config from a server with working static/dynamic compression?