# What is the key to static compression with IIS and ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis, compression

I have a ASP.NET website (.NET 4).  I've believe I have all the settings enabled to achieve gzip compression of static files but sites like Google Page Speed still report PNGs, javascript and CSS files as being uncompressed. Here is my setup:

**IIS: Website -> IIS -> Compression:**

[image: Static Compression Enabled in IIS]

**Web.config:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />   
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
          <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" dynamicCompressionLevel="10" staticCompressionLevel="10"/>     
          <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
            <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true"/>
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
          </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
```

is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Just guessing - I'd move that `<add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>` line to be the first inside `<staticTypes>` - it may be overriding the specific settings.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but no luck.  Even removed the "false" line with no effect

Comment: Just checking, your static files are mapped to the StaticFileModule in Handler Mappings, right?

Comment: When you look at the uncompressed .js or .css files, are they big? IIS has a lower limit under which files are not compressed even when compression is on. The setting is in the server-level Compression settings (it's not shown for individual web sites).

Comment: @xxbbcc Well the default entry "*" is mapped to the static handler and then the dynamic file types are mapped to their respective handlers.  No specific entries for CSS, JPEG, Png etc

Comment: @xbbbcc IIS reporting compression minimum is 2700 bytes.  Seeing an uncompressed CSS file of 23kb

Comment: JPEG and PNG files are already heavily compressed - they won't (and shouldn't) be further compressed - they'd likely increase in size.

Comment: @xxbbcc I'll grant you that.  CSS and JS still an issue

Comment: Yes I'd agree with that. :)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515426/static-compression-in-iis-does-not-work-for-htm-js-files

Comment: @xxbbcc see my answer post.  Seems enabling dynamic compression in your web.config when it is not enabled in IIS short-circuits all compression, including static. That is my brief analysis anyway. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out (at least I fixed it, here are the facts):

Per my original post screenshot, the dynamic compression module was not installed.  I noticed dynamic compression was enabled in my web.config (despite the module not being installed).

I disabled dynamic compression in my web.config (see below) and static compression started working! Thanks to **@xxbbcc** for the comment back an forth.

**old:**

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
```

**new:**

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
```